# Не отображается контент в AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, android-dialog

Есть `AlertDialog` для которого я сделал свой макет но при добавлении его таким способом как указано в документации:

**пример:**

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.ChatAlertDialogStyle);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_message_dialog, null));
    builder.create().show();
```

элементы которые находятся в layout не отображаются + размеры не соотвутствуют размерам указаным в верстке.

Comment: попробуйте `View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom, null);`

Comment: `ApplicationContext` не годится для `inflate`

Comment: Так получилось, но макет все равно не такого размера как у меня на макете, в чем может быть проблема, оно его вроде как растягивает

Comment: Как Вы определили,что размеры не соответствуют указанным в верстке, если они не отображаются?)

Comment: может так `return builder.create();`?

Answer (score 4):

Так попробуйте

```
 LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
 final View view = factory.inflate(R.layout.chat_message_dialog, null);
 AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.ChatAlertDialogStyle);
 alertDialog = alert.create();
 alertDialog.setView(view, 0, 0, 0, 0);
 alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: Попробовал не получилось!

Comment: значит у вас проблема в верстке

Answer (score 1):

Сделал  так:

```
public void showDialog() {
    AlertDialog alertDialog = null;
    LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    final View view = factory.inflate(R.layout.chat_message_dialog, null);

    DialogView dialogView = new DialogView(context);
    Log.e(TAG, "Dialog width: " + dialogView.getWidth() + " heigth: " + dialogView.getHeight());


    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.ChatAlertDialogStyle);
    alertDialog = alert.create();
    alertDialog.setView(view);
    alertDialog.show();
    alertDialog.getWindow().setLayout(600, 700);
}
```